# Nrf24l01 smd pcb placement tips

Tags: atmega328, nrf24l01+, pcb-design

I am working on pcb design with nrf24l01 smd. I have read somewhere that nrf24l01 module has problem while communication when it is placed with its antenna within the pcb. I want my module to be within the pcb as much as possible to save some space. I will be making the pcb at home and will be placing atmega 328p smd on the opposite layer. Should I fill the opposite layer with ground pad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep the ground plane away from the antenna. The rest of the module doesn't care (and having a ground plane under it can help with unwanted EMI).

Here's a design I did recently for a customer with the same module in it. It's placed near the edge of the PCB with the ground plane cut out around the antenna:

[image]

That layout is actually set up for either the small SMD, the SMD with PA+LNB or the thorugh-hole version. The important thing is that there is a nice big exclusion zone in the ground plane where the antenna is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer 

Comment: Hi @Majenko! Would it be okay to have the NRF24L01 module and ATMega module on the same PCB with also the antenna on the PCB?